# format sql query to postgresql query format in spring data jpa-jsonb column type

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I have a table Employee with fileds id, name, age , Address(as Jsonb string stored in Postgres DB)

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Employee")
 @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
 public class Employee  implements Serializable {
 @Id
 @Column
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 int Id;
 @Column
 String name;
 @Column
 int age;

 @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
 @Type(type="jsonb")
 Address address;   // this field is JSONB data stored in postgress DB

 // setter and getters

 }

 public class Address implements Serializable {

 String flatNo;
 String area;
 String state;

 // setter and getters
 }
 DB table data format:

 id |   name   | age |                        address  
 ---+----------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------
 20 | Peter    |  16 | {"area": "Kanpur", "state": "KARNATAKA", "flatNo": "78/1"}
 21 | Nani     |  20 | {"area": "CTM", "state": "TA", "flatNo": "111"}
```

My query here is: I need to filter data based on jsonb field.Here is my query :
 I have tried this with psql

```
 testdb=# select * from employee where address ->> 'area' = 'Kanpur';
 id | name | age |                     address
 ----+------+-----+-------------------------------------------------
 21 | James |  20 | {"area": "Kanpur", "state": "KARNATAKA", "flatNo": "78/1"}
 (1 row)



 @Repository
 public interface EmployeeRespository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer> {
 @Query("select e from employee e where e.address ->> 'area' = :area")
 public List findByArea(@Param("area") String age);
 }
```

When i try with java code in spring data jpa, its an error shown:

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: > near line 1, 
 column 57 [Select  e from com.web.rest.Employee e where e.address ->> 'area' = :area]
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~ 
 [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:297) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
```

area is not direct field of Employee object, how to map area to Address in query.
Please suggest.Thanks in advance.